# SparkR df read as one column

Tags: csv, apache-spark, sparkr

txt with 4 column divided by \t.

When I read it in this way:

```
A<-read.df(sqlContext,"/home/daniele/Tnt3.txt", "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

SparkR read it all as one column

```
 a\tb\tc\td
```

How can I change the **\t to ,**  in sparkR?

(I know that I can change it manually like this `sed -i 's/\t/,/g' file` but is a little bit slowly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/daniele/Tnt3.txt", "com.databricks.spark.csv", delimiter="\t")

Answer (score 0):

You should specify delimiter.

Im newer in R, but i think is something like this

A<-read.df(sqlContext,"/home/daniele/Tnt3.txt", "com.databricks.spark.csv").options("delimiter", "\t")

for more info, visit page of spark-csv:

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv